# django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (D:\img\favicon.ico) is located outside of the base path component (D:\test\static)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have facing this issue when i am trying to give favicon to my admin portal it was working completely fine till `DEBUG` was `True`. When I switch to `DEBUG=False` it start showing me this error which i mention in tittle.

here is my code :

templates/admin/base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static '/img/favicon.ico' %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
        ]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In debug it worked smoothly now it shows me error 400 in browser and in terminal:

`raise SuspiciousFileOperation( django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (D:\img\favicon.ico) is located outside of the base path component (D:\Social_login\staticfiles)`

Comment: Please also show your urls.py where you add url patterns for static files. In DEBUG=false Django is not supposed to handle static files thus in "normal" situation it could only show 404 error if webserver was not configured properly. If you see this error then I guess you have some manual solution for handling static files on prod with django.

Comment: if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: this is my url.py file i have putted this for hendling what your talking about

Comment: actually i solved this problem and i am laughing at my self i spend aroun 8 hours to find solution for it now i just have to do it remove "  /  " . use   {% static 'img/favicon.ico' % static '/img/favicon.ico' of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}    
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

It solved my problem just with the above code snippet.